# Why my own keymaps does not work in nvim for c++ but works for the other languages? (i'm using lua)

Tags: lua, neovim, keymaps

Recently I configured my nvim to use lsp. I add a couple of keymaps for my languages such as pressing ctrl-d goes to the definition of the function where the cursor is. This work good for every language but for c++ and I don't know why. It seems to me that c++ has it owns keymaps but I don't know how to replace them.

This is my lsp_config.lua file:

```
require("mason").setup()
require("mason-lspconfig").setup({
    ensure_installed = {
        "lua_ls",
        "bashls",
        "clangd",
        "hls",
        "elp",
        "pyright"
    }
})

local on_attach = function(_, _)

    vim.keymap.set('n', '<leader>rn', vim.lsp.buf.rename, {})
    vim.keymap.set('n', '<leader>co', vim.lsp.buf.code_action, {})
    vim.keymap.set('n', '<C-d>', vim.lsp.buf.definition, {})
    vim.keymap.set('n', '<C-i>', vim.lsp.buf.implementation, {})
    vim.keymap.set('n', '<C-r>', require('telescope.builtin').lsp_references, {})
    vim.keymap.set('n', 'K', vim.lsp.buf.hover, {})
    
    local capabilities = require('cmp_nvim_lsp').default_capabilities()
    local lspconfig = require("lspconfig")

    lspconfig.tsserver.setup({
        capabilities = capabilities
    })
    
    lspconfig.html.setup({
        capabilities = capabilities
    })
    
    lspconfig.lua_ls.setup({
        capabilities = capabilities
    })

end

require("lspconfig").lua_ls.setup {
    on_attach = on_attach
}

require("lspconfig").bashls.setup {
    on_attach = on_attach
}

require("lspconfig").clangd.setup {
    on_attach = on_attach
}

require("lspconfig").hls.setup {
    on_attach = on_attach
}

require("lspconfig").elp.setup {
    on_attach = on_attach
}

require("lspconfig").pyright.setup {
    on_attach = on_attach
}
```

I try to change the keymaps expecting it will solve the problem or searching another specific server for c++ but it seems to me that this is not the solution.
I've also tried installing g++-12 but it doesn't work either.

Comment: Even though this question is regarding neovim when editing C++, the question is not *itself* a C++ question.